# Regularly change environment variables

Tags: windows, configuration, environment-variables

I'm a developer and I work on some applications which need different environments.

One of my problems is related to the OS environment variables.

On Windows 7, do you know if there's a way to easily/regularly change the environment variables ?

Of course, I could change it manually but I'm looking for an easier solution.

Changes should be "permanent" till my next "task switch".

Comment: What kind of language do you use? Already used batch files?

Comment: I use java.I've already made small batch files. But I'm not sure these can be very convenient for development because the "set" command is temporary.

Answer (score 2):

Create a set of batch files that set the variables the way you need them, then run the appropriate one for your task.

The setx command line tool will set them permanently.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc755104(v=ws.10).aspx

Comment: or VB Script or powershell script

Comment: It seems batch files cannot permanently set environment variables (they are lost after a reboot for example). Still looking for a better alternative.

Comment: @Pierre, if the batch file runs the application then the application will see the variables set by the batch file.  So you can just create shortcuts to the various batch files and always use those instead of running the applications directly.

Comment: I think I'll give Resource Kit a try. Seems perfectly suitable for me. Thanks BNL !

Answer (score 0):

I think <kbd>Win+Break</kbd> is a real time saver in getting to any System Config screen.

Further more, you can import/export system/user environment variables from the registry:

- `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environment`
- `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Environment`

*Keep in mind that changing these will in not alter your running processes' environments*. My procedure for this:

1. Killing `explorer.exe` from the Task Manager, and then
2. `Run`-ning a new `explorer.exe` (from the File menu in that same Task Manager)

will usually do what you want. **Note** that this 'soft' reload does *not* include long-running background processes.

#### Bonus Tip

use [Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/nl-nl/sysinternals/bb896653) to view exactly *what* environment a running process is using:

[image]